# How can I save a final model after training it on chunks of data?

Tags: python, pandas

After training a model on chunks, how can I save the final model?

```
df = pd.read_csv(, chunksize=10000)
for chunk in df:
  text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
  filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
  joblib.dump(text_clf, filename)

# load the model from disk
loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)
```

Saving a model like this will just give me the model trained on the last chunk. How can I avoid that and get the overall model trained on every chunk?

**UPDATE:**
 Most of the real-world data sets are huge and can’t be trained in one go. How can I save a model after training it on each chunk of data?

```
df = pd.read_csv(“an.csv”, chunksize=6953)
for chunk in df:
  text = chunk[‘body’]
  label = chunk[‘user_id’]

  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text, label, test_size=0.3 )

  text_clf = Pipeline([(‘vect’, TfidfVectorizer()),
  (‘tfidf’, TfidfTransformer()),
  (‘clf’, LinearSVC()),
  ])

  text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

  # save the model to disk
  filename = ‘finalized_model.sav’
  joblib.dump(model, filename)
```

Will saving it this way give me the model trained on the entire dataset? I want the model trained on every chunk. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

One option is [Dask framework's incremental learning](https://ml.dask.org/incremental.html). That would automate the loading of chunks and applying `partial_fit` in scikit-learn.

The code would be something like:

```py
from dask_ml.datasets import make_classification
from dask_ml.wrappers import Incremental

X, y = make_classification(chunks=25)
estimator = LinearSVC(random_state=10, max_iter=100)
clf = Incremental(estimator)
clf.fit(X, y, classes=[0, 1])

joblib.dump(clf, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using 'fit' method, which basically overwrites the previous training and trains a new model, on your new chunk; that is why you are not able to save the model. 
You can think of this problem as an *'incremental training'* problem, and what you basically require is to **partially fit** using **partial_fit()** method. 
Make sure that your classification algorithm supports **partial_fit()**

Comment: Thank you for your response. For classifiers that don't support partial fit, what is a way to get past it?

Comment: I guess the only way to achieve a partial fit-like results without using partial_fit() or not having partial_fit is to write your own code which trains the model, stores the parameters, and updates them after every training. Moreover, you can use other frameworks, like Dask.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a pseudo code that you can kindly provide?

Comment: I tried looking up on the internet for it, however I don't find any. You can try other frameworks, like Dask (https://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/incremental.html)